# Existence of a continuous function with pre-image of each point  uncountable 

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ such that the pre-image $f^{−1}(y)$ of any point $y \in [0, 1]$ is uncountable?

Comment: 2 related questions on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18666/continuous-function-from-0-1-to-0-1, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47533/uncountable-preimage-of-every-point

Comment: Sample paths of Brownian motion satisfy this property with probability one (if you cap and floor it to keep it in the range $[0,1]$ that is).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes.**

One nice way to see that is to take a [Peano curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) $c: [0,1] \to [0,1]^{2}$ (that is, a continuous surjection) and to compose it with the projection $p(x,y) = x$. Then $f = p \circ c$ will have the desired property.

**Added.** This is a folklore construction illustrating how far from the graphs we can actually draw (or imagine) a continuous function can be. As mentioned by Jonas in the comments this construction appears in at least two MO threads, namely [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18666/continuous-function-from-0-1-to-0-1) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47533/uncountable-preimage-of-every-point). I don't know where this example appeared first, I suspect that it can be found in Hausdorff's *Mengenlehre*, but Peano or Hilbert may have noticed it before that. They're not mentioning it in their original papers, though: [Hilbert's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF01199431) and [Peano's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF01199438), links taken from the Wikipedia page on [space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).