# Zero divisors of $C[0,1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find the zero divisors of the ring $R=C[0,1]$ the continuous functions $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$.

I could thought of a set $S$ that I think is included in the set of zero divisors, but I am not sure if $S$ contains all the zero divisors. $S=\{f:[0,1] \to [0,1]: \text{there is} \space \epsilon>0, (x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \subset [0,1], f((x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon))=0\}$

I would like some help to find the zero divisors. Is the set $S$ a subset of the set of zero divisors? How can I show that?

Comment: What are the operations defined on $R$? Point-wise adition and multiplication?

Comment: Those you've mentioned.

Comment: And what is $x_0$ in your definition of $S$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/155944/3217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no doubt $S$ is a subset of the set of zero divisors. In fact, it contains *all* zero divisors in the specified ring.

Let $f\in C[0,1]\setminus S$, and we show that $f$ is not a zero divisor. Since $f\not\in S$, the set of zeros of $f$, $Z:=\{x\in[0,1]|f(x)=0\}$, does not contain any open interval. Assume now $g$ is another function such that $f\cdot g=0$. It follows that $g$ has a zero in every open interval, or in other words the set of zeros of $g$ is dense. Since $g$ is continuous, it follows that $g\equiv0$.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, if $fg = 0$ and $g \ne 0$, say $g(x_0) \ne 0$, then by continuity $g$ does not vanish in a neighborhood of $x_0$, so $f$ must

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct. If $f$ is a zero divisor, then there is some nonzero $g \in C[0,1]$ such that $fg = 0$. Suppose $g(x_0) \neq 0$. By continuity, $g(x)$ is nonzero on some an interval $I := (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and thus $f\vert_I = 0$.

Conversely, if $f \in C[0, 1]$ is zero on such an interval $I$, then one can choose $g$ that is nonzero at $x_0$ but zero on $[0, 1] - I$, and by construction $fg = 0$.