# Solve this integration $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^2+1)\delta{(x^2-x-6)}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I know that $\delta(g(x))=\sum_i\dfrac{\delta(x-x_i)}{g'(x)}$, but I want it's proof, *am not getting how to proof this*.

Comment: As the roots of $x^2-x-6$ are $-2$ and $3$, isn't the integral equal to : $(-2)^2+1 + 3^2+1$?

Comment: No the answer  is not what you have written, see the detail section.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389100/composition-of-the-derivative-of-dirac-delta-with-a-function/2389360#2389360

Answer (score 0):

First note that,

$$\delta_a(x) = 1 \qquad \text{if $x= a$ and $\delta_a(x) = 0$ if $x\neq a$}$$
and 
 for any measurable function $f$

$$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\delta_a(dx) = f(a).$$

$$\delta_0\equiv \delta.$$
 But $$ x^2 -x-6  =  0 \Longleftrightarrow  x=3 ~~or ~~x=-2$$

Hence

$$\delta(x^2 -x-6) = 1 \qquad \text{if $ x=3 $ or $x=-2$ and $\delta(x^2 -x-6) = 0 $ if else}$$

Therefore 
$$\delta(x^2 -x-6) =  \delta_3+\delta_{-2}$$

Hence for any  measurable  function $f$ we have

$$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\delta(x^2 -x-6)dx = \int_{\mathbb R}f(x) (\delta_3+\delta_{-2})dx= \int_{\mathbb R}f(x) \delta_3(dx)+\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\delta_{-2}(dx)= f(3)+f(-2)$$

Thus

$$\int_{\mathbb R}(x^2+1)\delta(x^2 -x-6)dx = 3^2+1+2^2+1 = 15$$

Comment: $\delta(0)$ is not equal to $1$, but rather some kind of infinity. Moreover wolfram|alpha [disagrees with the result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int((x%5E2%2B1)*dirac(x%5E2-x-6),+x+%3D+-infty..infty)). However I don't remember anything about dirac distribution-related integrals, so I can't say which is right. Edit: maybe change variables to get $\delta(u)$ in the integral?

Comment: You need to divide through by $|d/dx (x^2 - x - 6) |$ evaluated at each of the roots, i.e. $5$, which will then agree with wolfram

Comment: Bro the answer is wrong, see the detail section and plz give a proof

Answer (score 0):

**I know the answer, the integration will give**

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^2+1)\delta(x^2-x-6)\,dx$

$\implies\displaystyle\delta(x^2-x-6)=\delta\left[(x+2)(x-3)\right]=\frac{\delta(x+2)}{-5}+\frac{\delta(x-3)}{5}$

**So, the integration becomes**

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^2+1)\left[\frac{\delta(x+2)}{-5}+\frac{\delta(x-3)}{5}\right]\,dx$

$\implies\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{-5}|_{x=-2}+\dfrac{(x^2+1)}{5}|_{x=3}=1$

But what’s my doubt is , **How to proof this?**

$\implies\displaystyle\delta(x^2-x-6)=\delta\left[(x+2)(x-3)\right]=\frac{\delta(x+2)}{-5}+\frac{\delta(x-3)}{5}$

Help me Guys

**EDIT**

**This is how I tried the proof**

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta[(x-a)(x-b)]\,dx$

**But we know that**
$\displaystyle\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta[(x-a)(x-b)]\,d[(x-a)(x-b)]=1}$

**Right?**

$\implies\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(2x-(a+b))\delta[(x-a)(x-b)]\,dx=1$

**So**,

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta[(x-a)(x-b)]\,\frac{d[(x-a)(x-b)]}{2x-(a+b)}$

$\implies\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int_{0}^{a+\epsilon}+\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b}\right)f(x)\delta[(x-a)(x-b)]\,\frac{d[(x-a)(x-b)]}{2x-(a+b)}$

$\implies\left(\dfrac{f(a)}{2a-(a+b)}+\dfrac{f(b)}{2b-(a+b)}\right)$

**Hence**, $\displaystyle\boxed{\delta[g(x)]=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{g'(x)}}\tag*{}$

**REGARDS!**

**VM**