# Dirac delta function of function

Tags: taylor-expansion, dirac-delta

How to derive below equation?

\begin{equation}
\delta(g(x))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-a_i)}{\lvert g^\prime(a_i)\rvert}.\qquad (*)
\end{equation}
I found a solution like equations below:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(g(x))&=&\sum_i\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}f(x)\delta(g(x))\ dx,\qquad g(a_i)=0\\
&=&\sum_i\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}f(x)\delta((x-a_i)g^\prime(a_i))\ dx,\qquad (x-a_i)g^\prime(a_i)\ \text{is leading term in its Taylor seires.}\\
&=&\sum_i\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}f(x)\frac{1}{\lvert g^\prime(a_i)\rvert}\delta(x-a_i)\ dx,\qquad \delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)\\
\end{eqnarray}

So, $\delta(g(x))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-a_i)}{\lvert g^\prime(a_i)\rvert}.$

But comparing equations at fisrt line with third,

$\delta(g(x))=\frac{\delta(x-a_i)}{\lvert g^\prime(a_i)\rvert}.$

What's wrong with above equations? And why use leading term only? eq (*) is approximation?

So my questions are:

1. When compare with first and third line which are represented below eq (*), Where $\sum_i$ in RHS of Eq (*) come from?
2. Why use leading term only? eq (*) is approximation? Is it exist that another precise derivation?

Please understand my poor English.

Comment: What are $a_i's?$

Comment: @GuyFsone he said that those are zeroes of g.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389100/composition-of-the-derivative-of-dirac-delta-with-a-function/2389360#2389360

Answer (score 1):

For the first question about the summation note that your domain $(-\infty,+\infty)$ must be splitted in many parts as much there are zeroes of $g$. That's the meaning of the sum. For the second question, suppose that $\tilde{x}$ is such that $g(\tilde{x})=0$ and $g$ a bijection. Then 
$$I=\int f(x)\delta(g(x))dx$$
can be rewritten as
$$\int f(g^{-1}(y))\delta(y)\frac{\partial g^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}dy$$ 
where $x=g^{-1}(y)$.
Then you obtain
$$I=f(g^{-1}(0))\frac{\partial g^{-1}(0)}{\partial y}$$
or
$$I=\frac{f(g(\tilde{x}))}{g'(\tilde{x})}$$
given that
$$\frac{\partial g^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial g(y)}{\partial y}}.$$

Comment: Please is g a bijection? because otherwise I understand your change of variavles