# How to prove $\delta [g(x)]= \sum_i \frac{\delta (x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|} $

Tags: dirac-delta

How to prove $\delta [g(x)]= \sum_i \frac{\delta (x-x_i)}{|g'(x_i)|} $

This is given as a property I came upon on [MathWorld - Delta Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html). This is very helpful in proving other properties of the delta function such as $\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{a}\delta(x)$

Comment: Also is there another way to prove $\delta(x^2-a^2) = \frac{1}{2a} (\delta(x+a)+\delta(x-a))$ without this so-called property?

Comment: When $g$ has $C^1$ inverse, then integration by substitution easily proves the relation. When $g$ has isolated zeros and has local $C^1$ inverses near each zero, then you can split the integral (against a test function, of course) over the intervals near zeros of $g$ and then apply the previous observation to each of the integrals.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389360/168433

Comment: **What is your definition of $\delta(g(x))$**

Comment: @md2perpe do you have a more intuitive example?

Comment: @reuns so $g(x)$ is a random *nice* function, and $\delta(x)$ is the typical Dirac delta function, hopefully that answers your concern?

Comment: No. I'm asking for the definition of $\delta(g(x))$.

Comment: Note that it is quite tricky to rigorously define $\delta(\cdot)$, because the idea of the Dirac delta and integral of function does not get along. Mathematicians introduce the notion of [*distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) to overcome this difficulty, but then distribution in general do not behave well under "composition" (if such a thing is well defined at all). So, your input on the definition of $\delta(g(x))$ is very important for proving the property.

Comment: @reuns sorry for the undefined term (I took it for granted because that's what appeared in my textbook), I think in some books it is written as $(f*g)$, so $f(g(x))\equiv (f*g)$

Comment: @IanHsiao. Composition is usually written with a small circle: $(f\circ g)(x) := f(g(x)).$ The problem here is that $\delta$ is not a function but a distribution, which is a functional on a space of very nice "test functions," so the composition $\delta\circ g$ cannot be defined the usual way.

Comment: @md2perpe okay, thanks for the clearification!