# Find a differentiable $f$ such that $\mathrm{Zeros}(f)=\mathbb{any\; closed \;set}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set.

How to prove that there is a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$Z(f)=B$$

where $$Z(f)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:f(x)=0\}$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)

Comment: Take a look at the first answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40557/a-nontrivial-everywhere-continuous-function-with-uncountably-many-roots . It might help. And this http://mathoverflow.net/a/24040 .

Comment: Here is a cute solution in one dimension (it may be standard): Given $B$ closed, start with $g(x)=\mathrm{dist}(x,B)$, so $g(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$, $g(x)=0$ iff $x\in B$, and $g$ is continuous. Now let $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\,dt$, so $f$ is increasing, and $f'(x)=0$ iff $g(x)=0$ iff $x\in B$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo You constructed a differentiable function such that the zero set of $f' $ is $B$ ... not the zero set of $f$.

Comment: @PostNoBills Ah, how silly! Oh, well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will adapt the  [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/24040) by Harald Hanche-Olsen, filling in some details, and taking into account that you don't ask for $C^\infty$, but only for a differentiable function.

Let 
$$E_0=\{x\colon\operatorname{dist}(x,B)\ge 1 \}$$
and for $k=1,2,\ldots$ let 
$$E_k=\{x\colon 2^{-k}\le \operatorname{dist}(x,B)\le  2^{1-k}\}$$
These sets cover the complement of $B$. Also let 
$$F_k=\{x\colon  \operatorname{dist}(x,E_k)\le  2^{-k-2}\}$$
be an "enlargement" of $E_k$ which still stays away from $B$.

Let $\omega$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\omega\ge 0$, $\omega(x)=0$ when $|x|\ge 1/2$, and $\omega(x)>0$ when $|x|\le 1/4$. Let $\omega_k(x) = \omega( 2^{ k}x)$.

The convolution of $\chi_{F_k}$ with $\omega_k$ has the following properties:

- it is as smooth as $\omega$ is
- it is nonnegative
- it is zero on the set $ \{x\colon  \operatorname{dist}(x,F_k) >  2^{-k-1}\}$, which contains the set $ \{x\colon  \operatorname{dist}(x,B ) < 2^{-k-2}\}$
- it is strictly positive on $E_k$
- it does not exceed $4^{-k}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \omega$.

Define
$$f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  (\chi_{F_k}*\omega_k) \tag{1}$$
and observe that

- $f$ is strictly positive on the complement of $B$, and vanishes   on $B$.
- $f$ satisfies an estimate of the form $f(x)\le C(\operatorname{dist}(x,B ))^2$, because at distance about $2^{-k}$ from $B$
  it takes values about $4^{-k}$
- By the above, $f$ is differentiable on $B$.
- $f$ is also differentiable on the complement of $B$, because every point of this complement has a neighborhood in 
  which only finitely many terms of (1) are nonzero.

---

As Harald Hanche-Olsen notes, introducing a rapidly decaying weight one can make the sum $C^\infty$ smooth, e.g.,
$$f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  2^{-k^2} (\chi_{F_k}*\omega_k )$$

Comment: Very neat! ${}$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using the fact that every open subset of the reals can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals.

EDIT: Sorry, misread the question, and I believe there's a simpler solution anyway. Can you think of a solution that produces a continuous function and modify it to be differentiable? What kind of function might be zero everywhere in a set and nonzero outside it?

Comment: $B\subseteq\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Do you know yourself what you are hinting at with "modify it to be differentiable"?

Comment: You're right; I should have been more careful. My intention was that you could square the distance, but if the original set is two parallel lines this doesn't fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work?

Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set. Define a function $f$
$$ f(x) = \text{dist}(x,B)$$
where
$$ \text{dist}(x,B) = \inf_{b\in B} d(x,b)  $$

Comment: Why is $f$ differentiable?

Comment: @user44541 : I'm sure this $f$ is not differentiable, and pretty sure there is an easy way to fix that.

Comment: I was just throwing ideas out. From topology the "distance to set function" is always continuous in the metric topology so it might be a good candidate to extend

Comment: Your proposed function $f(x)$ is differentiable at a point $x\notin B$ if and only if dist$(x,B)=d(x,b)$ for a unique element $b\in B$; this was a [problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27641903) of the American Mathematical Monthly.