# If $A=\{ f^{-1}(y)\}$ is uncountable can we find an open interval $I$ such that the set $A$ is dense in $I$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that there is $y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is uncountable. Can it be show that 
>   $$\underline{D}f(x)=\liminf_{z\to x}\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}=0$$
>   at some $x\in A=\{ f^{-1}(y)\}$ or perhaps at a lot (all?) of $x\in A$? 
>   Can we get better results if we assume $f$ is nowhere monotone ?

If so then according to [Existence of a continuous function with pre-image of each point  uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/existence-of-a-continuous-function-with-pre-image-of-each-point-uncountable) , there would be a continuous and surjective real-valued function such that $\underline{D}f(x)=0$ for all points in the domain!

> If instead we assume only that $A$ is infinite, can we still find at least one $x$ such that   $\underline{D}f(x)=0$?

Comment: You're using $y$ for two different things. Once as a constant (the function value that is taken infinitely many times) and once as a variable (in the limit value expression).

Comment: @Arthur I will edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the second question is negative. Take $s(x):[0,1]\to[0,1]$ as the continuous function defined as $2x$ over $[0,1/2]$ and $2-2x$ over $[1/2,1]$, then take $f:[0,1)\to[0,1]$ defined as:
$$f(x)=s\left(\left\{\frac{1}{1-x}\right\}\right).$$
For any $y\in[0,1]$ we have $|f^{-1}(y)|=\aleph_0$ but $\underline{D}$ is never zero.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not entirely convinced about the second part. For example, as you said $f^(y)$ is closed and by assumption uncountable so it contains a perfect set where all points are limit points. From this we can show that $\underline{D}(x)$ is zero in the perfect set so it is zero in at least an uncountable set (perfect sets are uncountable).

Comment: As for the counter-example did you mean $g=s$ or something else? If you meant $g=s$ I don't understand why $f^{-1}(y)$ is infinite for each $y$...

Comment: I retired the second part of my answer since I saw it was flawed. But for the first part, just consider that $f(x)$ is a triangular wave with an increasing frequency as $x$ approaches $1$.